# How i can map enum class to attributes from other object?

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, enums, annotations

I have two classes, one of them is a map with name and position of a tabbed file:

```
public enum fieldPosition {
     field_1(0),
     field_2(1),
     // other fields
}
```

The other is a simple entity:

```
public class simpleEntiy {
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    // other attributes
}
```

I want to generate a tabbed file based on position of enum class, but using the object from entity class with spring annotations. Its possible?
Is there some way to use map on entity class to mapper the enum class? 
For example:

```
public class simpleEntiy {
    //some annotation to field_1 or position 0
    private String name;
    //some annotation to field_2 or position 1
    private String desc;
    // other attributes
}
```

I'm using java 8 and spring boot 1.4.3.
Thanks